# Routes conflict in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need the next 3 routes:

```
get "", to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}")
get '/:locale/', to: "home#index"
get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false
```

In this case when I go to `domain.com` it redirects me to the `domain.com/en`. It's ok. But when I type `domain.com/feed` it rise an error. How can I solve this error?

Can I write something like this

```
if params[:locale] == "en"
   get "", to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}")
   get '/:locale/', to: "home#index"
else
   get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false
end
```

Or something else?

An error:

```
"feed" is not a valid locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @nathanvda look at the question, please

Comment: Your comment seems to suggest I did not read your question, yet you just edited it to add it. Tssss.

Comment: @nathanvda I just add it to my question and that's why I did ask you to read my question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "constrain" the locale route first, or otherwise it will catch all. So do something like

```
get '/:locale/', to: "home#index", constraints: {locale: /en|de/}
```

See [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) you can give a regex to constrain a route, in this case: only allow `en` and `de` locales.

This gets tedious if your list of locales is long and might change in the future, so you could also write:

```
get '/:locale/', to: "home#index", constraints: {locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ }
```